# Postgres extract() Year doesn't work inside an insert

Tags: postgresql, date

I have this insert query:

```
INSERT INTO passation 
VALUES 
(default,0,0,0,0,SELECT extract(YEAR FROM now()),'Nouvelle Passation','Téléphonique',now(),'Normale',0)
```

But the year doesn't work, I don't know why, please help because, alone, it works:

```
SELECT extract(YEAR FROM now())
```

This is the Postgres error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 2: ...default,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,SELECT ext...
                                                             ^

********** Erreur **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
État SQL :42601
Caractère : 82
```

Do I have to put the year into a variable?

Comment: `INSERT INTO passation select default,0,0,0,0, extract(YEAR FROM now()),'Nouvelle Passation','Téléphonique',now(),'Normale',0`

Comment: Tryed but still have an error ... Thank you

Comment: what is `default`?

Comment: BenH's comment is correct, the `select` is wrong and what he suggested **will** work: http://rextester.com/NBB7282 if you have a new error then you are not telling us everything

Comment: default is the serial column auto incremented value

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "default"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO passation SELECT default,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...
                                     ^

********** Erreur **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "default"
État SQL :42601
Caractère : 30

Comment: You cannot use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with `DEFAULT`. The `DEFAULT` keyword can only be used in `INSERT INTO ... VALUES`. If you want `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` & default values, just omit the column(s) you want to use defaults for (and mark the columns, which have values in the `SELECT`, like in a_horse_with_no_name's note).

Comment: Sorry, there must have been a syntax error that i didn't see, it is working now :

Comment: INSERT INTO passation VALUES (default,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,extract(YEAR FROM now()),'Nouvelle Passation','Téléphonique',now(),'Normale',0) ;

Comment: Ooops yes it was the SELECT who needed to be removed, well done thanks a lot !

Comment: BTW If you want to use `select` in such way you should to surround it by parenthesizes: `VALUES (default,0,0,0,0,(SELECT extract(YEAR FROM now())),...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `SELECT` - use the expression "as is":

```
INSERT INTO passation 
VALUES 
(default,0,0,0,0,extract(YEAR FROM now()),'Nouvelle Passation','Téléphonique',now(),'Normale',0)
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/NBB7282

---

Note that not specifying the target columns is considered bad coding style. Something like:

```
 INSERT INTO passation (id, col1, col2, ....) 
 values ....
```

is better.

---

Apparently you are also trying to store the week number in another column. I would not do that. Just store the value of `now()` in one single column. That way you store the complete information any you can then extract the year, month, day, second or whatever you want at any time later.

Comment: Thank you, ok about your remark, but i have to copy an ancient program who was designed like this already, and it works well (week numbers, years separated), so i can copy ancient sql queries

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `SELECT` from the `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO passation 
VALUES (
   DEFAULT,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   extract(YEAR FROM now()),
   'Nouvelle Passation',
   'Téléphonique',
   now(),
   'Normale',
   0
);
```

Comment: Then how do i get the year ?

Comment: I also need to insert this : 
SELECT extract(WEEK FROM now());